# Is there any official Forgotten Realms localization for H1-E3 after H2?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures, forgotten-realms

I've once saw official indications about how to set both Keep on the Shadowfell (H1) and Thunderspire Labyrinth (H2) in the Forgotten Realms, specifically on the border between Cormyr and Sembia and near the East Way three day's distance from the first place respectively.

I've not been able to find any evidence of similar articles detailing a re-setting of the following adventures of the same line from Points of Light to Faerun.
Are there any?
If so, where can I read about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forgotten realms conversion for H-1 Keep on the Shadowfell appeared in Dungeon Magazine issue 155 and the conversion for H-2 following it in Dungeon Magazine issue 156. The official conversion articles end after H-2 and based on the preface by Greg Bilsland for the conversion of H-1 it seems that the articles were launch material created for the release of 4th edition "With this guide, a DM can jumpstart his Forgotten Realms campaign before the three core d&d books even arrive on the shelves." There is no official forgotten realms conversion for H-3 and beyond.